# Array return are sort in reverse and i dont know why

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua, lua-table, garrys-mod

I have a weird problem that I can't solve since yesterday on Garry's Mod (GLua)
When my gmod server game is running, I notice that there are errors on arrays that are empty with certain keys when they are well specified, while doing deep tests, I noticed that the returned arrays were ... backwards.

Here is an array below:

```
bigArray = {
    [ "default" ] = { 4, 2, 1 },
    [ "police" ] = { 4, 2, 1 },
    [ "mayor" ] = { 5, 2, 1 },
    [ "sherif" ] = { 6, 2, 1 },
}
```

Good, next I will use the `PrintTable()` method (*`PrintTable()` is a method already integrated in the game*) which displays the contents of an array (This method, normally if I run `PrintTable(bigArray)` the result should be literally the array above, but here is the result displayed:

```
{
    [ "sherif" ] = { 6, 2, 1 },
    [ "mayor" ] = { 5, 2, 1 },
    [ "police" ] = { 4, 2, 1 },
    [ "default" ] = { 4, 2, 1 },
}
```

I will put an example more telling since the previous one is an dictionary and not really an array :

```
table = {
   'truc',
   'machin',
   'chose'
   }
```

If I display the first element of the table like this `print(table[1])`, the displayed result will be: `chose`

Flipping the tables upside down makes a lot of addons I use crash, I have no idea how this happened, it happened suddenly without me modifying any addon (I already looked at the worshop addons, none of them are responsible for the problem)
If someone has an idea how this could be caused, I'm interested, thanks.

**Edit :**
I installed my project on a virtual machine, and when I launched the server, I had none of the errors I mentioned.
I formatted my entire machine containing the errors and since then the problem is solved.

Following this observation, I still think that the problem did not come from the code, maybe my assembler or the game was corrupted, who knows.

Thanks for those who tried to answer my problem, and if someone one day encounters the same problem, I strongly advise him to check the integrity of their game.

Comment: maybe because "Note that, for Lua, arrays also have no order." [quote](https://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html)

Comment: It looks like some of your addons rely on an undefined order of iteration.

Comment: `print(table[1]), the displayed result will be: chose` - not reproducible, arrays and table keys do not have the same behavior :). Note that the order is not reversed there is [no order to keys in a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECv0k.png) (i.e. you cannot and should not expect any order).

Comment: Maybe GarrysMod has its own implementation of Lua tables.  GMod Lua is pretty different from vanilla Lua.

Comment: @AD7six I know they don't have any particular order, especially in a for, but the index isn't supposed to change suddenly like that, especially on scripts I've never touched, so far the index has always been in the order it is declared.

Comment: Please post your code about how you check the order of elements of a table.  If the method you are using is `PrintTable` then the problem is not in Lua, but in this particular function.  How an addon can be affected by wrong behavior of `PrintTable`?  If you are invoking `table[1]` then the problem might be in the global variable `table` which is designed to point to standard Lua library `table` instead of some user data.

Comment: @ESkri PrinTable() is a method already integrated in the game, I will put you the link of the method if you want, but this method has no importance, it was just to illustrate the result that was returned, when I define a variable via a table according to an index, the variable will have an element of the table that does not correspond to the index indicated to the one declared in the table.
https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Global.PrintTable

Comment: Currently I can literally uninstall all my addons as well as my scripts, create a single file in which I declare only the example I presented, the table will always be returned backwards, on `table`, if I ask for index 1, it will be `chose` that will be returned.

Comment: `Currently I can literally ...` please literally edit the question to show doing exactly that. As I said previously your 'the displayed result will be: chose' claim is not reproducible. If you are using printTable to debug things note that that method [sorts the keys a-z](https://github.com/Facepunch/garrysmod/blob/master/garrysmod/lua/includes/util.lua#L66-L69) I think this is the point of confusion - once clarified please _edit the question_ to focus on your problem and not the (demonstrably false) statement that lua does not maintain order of array keys.

Comment: Do not use global variable named `table`, it is reserved by Lua, change the name please.  You should not pass data to an addon by using `table` table as a storage.

Comment: Please show code how you pass data to an addon and how the addon reads it.

Answer (score 4):

> I noticed that the returned arrays were ... backwards

They are not arrays. They are dictionaries (unordered set of key-value pairs).

An array in Lua would look like the following:

```
bigArray = {
    { name="default", 4, 2, 1 },
    { name="police",  4, 2, 1 },
    { name="mayor",   5, 2, 1 },
    { name="sherif",  6, 2, 1 },
}
```

In this case order of elements is preserved:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> bigArray = {
    { name="default", 4, 2, 1 },
    { name="police",  4, 2, 1 },
    { name="mayor",   5, 2, 1 },
    { name="sherif",  6, 2, 1 },
}
> bigArray[1].name # This will _always_ be "default"
default
```

Comment: Ok, but the problem remains the same, they are all returned backwards whether they are arrays or dictionaries

Comment: @MrMarrant please edit the question to demonstrate that.

Comment: @AD7six I do, in the new example the elements change position, "chose" goes from index 3 to index 1 and that without manipulation.

Comment: @MrMarrant There is no demonstration of that in the question and it would be a rather significant problem for the language if array keys could not be relied upon - hence it’s important to see a demonstration and not just a “I am seeing x” statement.

Answer (score 3):

In Garry's Mod dictionaries are not stored in any particular order. If you want to iterate through a dictionary in order, rather than  using `pairs` you must use either `SortedPairs`, `SortedPairsByMemberValue` or `SortedPairsByValue`.
See [this](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Global.SortedPairs) wiki page for reference.

For your implementation, I would recommend adding a field to each member value of your `bigArray` dictionary to specify a sort order; for instance:

```
local bigArray = {
    [ "default" ] = {
        sortOrder = 1,
        myValues = { 4, 2, 1 }
    },
    [ "police" ] = {
        sortOrder = 2,
        myValues = { 4, 2, 1 }
    },
    [ "mayor" ] = {
        sortOrder = 3,
        myValues = { 5, 2, 1 }
    },
    [ "sherif" ] = {
        sortOrder = 4,
        myValues = { 6, 2, 1 }
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to iterate in order of the `sortOrder` value, like so:

```
for key, value in SortedPairsByMemberValue(bigArray, "sortOrder") do
    print("\n" .. key .. ":")
    PrintTable(value)
end
```